# ASP.NET C# Gridview Cell URL Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

ok the following is the code for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BorderColor="#3399FF" BorderStyle="Solid" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10" 
    DataKeyNames="Request_No" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#3399FF" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Request_No" HeaderText="Request No" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Request_No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Request_Details" HeaderText="Request Details" 
            SortExpression="Request_Details" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="Request_Status" HeaderText="Request Status" 
            SortExpression="Request_Status" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have the three columns, and I want the last column cell data to be hyperlinks. So when I press that link, it will go to another page so that I could retrieve the cell value there and call details of request from database. This is simple enough in PHP but here am not sure how :(
Thanks and help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try this one.

http://www.aspexception.com/resourcedepot/howto_gridviewurl.aspx

Comment: Any idea how to change the raw value of request no in fields to Review Request literal?

Edit: got it! it's DataTextFormatString :)

Answer (score 2):

To do it you need to use [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) instead of `<asp:BoundField DataField="Request_Status"` something like:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <a href="requiredUrl">link text</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In order to get data binding in that template you can use [Bind, Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) methods

Comment: the HyperLinkField worked well thanks, but this is also good for future references...I might need to use it alter or change the current technique :)

Comment: Any idea how to change the raw value of request no in fields to Review Request literal?